# Iteration over sliced list to remove digits in Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, list-comprehension

I have this list, which is the ranking from a Fantasy Soccer League scraped from a website:

```
rank = ['1', 'Kaufman Foundation0', '0', '2', 'sasicc e friarielli0', '0', '3', 'Mordi1992 Team0', '0', '4', 'Japanese Cry Team0', '0', '5', 'Le Rondini FC0', '0', '6', 'Team Mclaury0', '0', '7', 'Team Discio0', '0', '8', 'Papa Sarto Calcio0', '0']
```

And I want to remove the annoying 0 at the end of every string that contain the name of the team.

I tried this

```
for i in range(len(rank[1::3])):
    rank[i] = ''.join([x for x in rank[1::3] if not x.isdigit()])
```

No success.
I want the list "rank" modified properly so I can print it.
I copied the list comprehension line from another post cause it worked if I used on a singolar element of the list but of course is not working inside the for loop.

The output should be:

```
1 - Kaufman Foundation 0 
2 - sasicc e friarielli 0
...
```

What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: Please update your question with your required output. Do you want `rank` to remain almost the same as it is now?

Comment: Updated. I want "rank" to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the middle of every 3 items in `rank` and update it:

```py
rank = ['1', 'Kaufman Foundation0', '0', '2', 'sasicc e friarielli0', '0', '3', 'Mordi1992 Team0', '0', '4', 'Japanese Cry Team0', '0', '5', 'Le Rondini FC0', '0', '6', 'Team Mclaury0', '0', '7', 'Team Discio0', '0', '8', 'Papa Sarto Calcio0', '0']

for i in range(1, len(rank), 3):
    rank[i] = rank[i][:-1]

print(rank)
```

Output:

```
['1', 'Kaufman Foundation', '0', '2', 'sasicc e friarielli', '0', '3', 'Mordi1992 Team', '0', '4', 'Japanese Cry Team', '0', '5', 'Le Rondini FC', '0', '6', 'Team Mclaury', '0', '7', 'Team Discio', '0', '8', 'Papa Sarto Calcio', '0']
```

Comment: How about ```rstrip('0')```

Comment: Ok, `rank[i] = rank[i].rstrip('0')` also works.

Answer (score 2):

```
rank = ['1', 'Kaufman Foundation0', '0', '2', 'sasicc e friarielli0', '0', '3', 'Mordi1992 Team0', '0', '4', 'Japanese Cry Team0', '0', '5', 'Le Rondini FC0', '0', '6', 'Team Mclaury0', '0', '7', 'Team Discio0', '0', '8', 'Papa Sarto Calcio0', '0']
rank_=[l.rstrip('0') for l in rank[1::3]]
```

Try this

```
rank_=[rank[0]]+[n.rstrip('0') if m%3==0 else n for m, n in enumerate(rank[1::])]
print(rank_)
```

Comment: But this does not change the `rank` list, it simply makes another list with the names. All the other elements like the numbers - 1,0 are not in the new list.

Comment: PCM is right. This works but I need then to merge it with the original list, keeping every team's name in the original position.

Comment: All you need is to add `rank[1::3] = rank_`

Answer (score 0):

- If the list item is numeric, keep it.
- Else, remove the trailing "0" from it.

```
rank = [x[:-1] if not x.isnumeric() else x for x in rank]
>>> rank
['1', 'Kaufman Foundation', '0', 
 '2', 'sasicc e friarielli', '0', 
 '3', 'Mordi1992 Team', '0', 
 '4', 'Japanese Cry Team', '0', 
 '5', 'Le Rondini FC', '0', 
 '6', 'Team Mclaury', '0', 
 '7', 'Team Discio', '0', 
 '8', 'Papa Sarto Calcio', '0']
```